# How to display value in <select> from mysql db using php?

Tags: php, mysql, select, drop-down-menu

I have a form in php where I need to select value from DB (phpmyadmin) using php. When I add my code its not working. Can anyone please check this code?

```
    <form role="form" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Category Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="code">Code:</label>
       <select>
      <?php 
/* change character set to utf8 */
        if (!mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")) {
            printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
            exit();
        } else {
            $rslt=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from category") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        }

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rslt)){
              echo $row;
                echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['code'] . "</option>";
        }
    ?>
        </select>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="rank">Rank:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rank" id="rank" placeholder="Enter Category Rank ">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="tag">Tags:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tag" id="tag" placeholder="Enter Category tag ">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Done</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: `$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)`, Ahh! no. where are you getting `$sql` from? this line should rather be like: `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rslt)`

Comment: pls check updated one

Comment: you're still mixing mysql API's with mysqli

Comment: please remove  "echo $row;" inside select

Comment: You need a full debug on this code, the question asked is just one of the problems you'll be having with it.

Comment: tag is there pls check

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari working now .thanks.... pls add ur comment as answer i can accpet that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving forward from the comments, this is what was needed:

Instead of:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
```

Should have been:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rslt){
```

> Notice: There are a few other warnings too. But that's *only* if you
>   care. cheers

Comment: i will accept result in 3 minutes, meanwhile one more doubt  i need to send this selected drop down list value to php file for  insertion. so how could i get selected value from dropdown?

Comment: @Bangalore this is exactly what I was going to comment next, you need to fetch the corresponding values from the database in a way like:     `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rslt))
    {    
    $db_cat_value = $row['id'];                
    $db_cat_name = $row['code'];                 
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $db_cat_value; ?>" ><?php echo $db_cat_name;?></option>` Where I have taken a dummy column `id` which in your case might be different.